# Rigify Rig moves twice as fast as the Armature Root bone after parenting everything to the Root

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, rigify

i'm working with a rig that i will be using in Unreal Engine 4, and to avoid compatibility issues, i have parented to the Root bone everything that was not parented to it, but this makes the Rig move twice as fast in any direction than the Root bone.

I guess it's a problem with the root affecting the Rig twice through the bones i reparented, but i have no idea how to fix it.

Here's a gif showing the problem:

[image]

Here's the hierarchy:

[image]

The hierarchy is not fully open because it wouldn't fit here, but just know that the groups starting with MCH are the ones i parented to the Root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix everything by just making another skeleton using a different hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have two armature nodes where you only want one. Look into this possibility. In my experience, double transformation weirdness can often be traced to having an extra armature node that was created accidentally. This often happens by the old armature node not being deleted before trying to rebind a mesh. An armature node will be created every time you try to bind a mesh, even if that mesh already has an armature node attached to it.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what an armature node is. Where would i find the duplicate one and delete it?

Comment: I could have just said Armature. You might have an extra one. If you do, you will see both of them in the standard place in the Properties Panel under the Modifier tab (wrench icon). Select your mesh and then look at your modifier stack. Do you see more than one armature listed? if so, delete one of them. Might you get the wrong one? Sure. If you delete the wrong one, your mesh will no longer be bound to the armature. Just undo in that case and delete the other one.

Comment: Oh, i had considered that before, but no, there is only one armature. The problem has to do with parenting the MCH- bones to the root, if i unparent them it moves normally, but i need to have them under the root hierarchy for UE4, so i can't

Comment: Are you willing to share your file so that someone here can take a look at it?

Comment: I managed to fix everything by just making another skeleton using a different hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because those bones that you reparented have a bone constraint to the root bone which also applies the transform.

Go into *Pose Mode* then under *Rig > Pose > root > [reparented bone] > Constraints > SWITCH_PARENT*, disable it with the eye icon. You can also select the reparented bone and go to the Bone Constraint Properties tab to disable or delete the *SWITCH_PARENT* constraint.

That solved the problem for me when I ran into it, but I'm not sure if it has other consequences to the rig.